# Tricky weak-* convergence question

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $K$ be a compact (let's say, $K=[0,1]$ to be concrete) and let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of Radon measures converging weakly-* to another Radon measure $\mu$ on $K$. Let $h : K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function vanishing only a finite set, and assume that 
$\mu_n/h$ and $\mu/h$ are all well-defined Radon measures (ie $1/h$ is integrable for all those measures).

Is it true that $\mu_n/h$ converges weakly-* to $\mu/h$ ?

It should be noted that in general for a non-continuous function $g$, weak-* convergence of $\mu_n$ to $\mu$ does not imply weak-* convergence of $g \mu_n$ to $g \mu$ when those measures are well-defined : it's easy to construct counter examples with diracs and functions vanishin everywhere but on a finite set. However I think in my setting it should be true, intuitively because the $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ could not charge the zeroes of $h$ too much, and because elsewhere $1/h$ is continuous.

My idea for proving this was to take a continuous function $f$ and try to verify convergence of $\int f/h d\mu_n$ to $\int f/h d\mu$ by truncating $1/h$ near its singularities. 
However I lack uniformity in $n$ to gain the convergence.

Any help appreciated.